# John 1:4-5. If life is the light of men, what is the darkness?

Tags: greek, john

John 1:4-5 NKJV

> 4 In Him was life, and the **life was the light of men.** 5 And the
> light shines in the darkness, and the darkness did not comprehend it.

What is the darkness?

Answer (score 1):

A comment from the article ["Follow the Light of the World"](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1993242#h=21) from the *Watchtower* of April 1, 1993, says:

> Light stands for truth and righteousness,in contrast with darkness, which stands for error and unrighteousness. Thus John shows that the darkness will not conquer the light.

Answer (score 0):

The verse in John 1:5 about darkness appears to be a direct allusion to Isa 9:1, 2 - a prophecy fulfilled by Jesus:

> Nevertheless, there will be no more gloom for those in distress. In
> the past He humbled the land of Zebulun and the land of Naphtali, but
> in the future He will honor the Way of the Sea, beyond the Jordan,
> Galilee of the nations: The people walking in darkness have seen a
> great light; on those living in the land of the shadow of death, a
> light has dawned.

Indeed, the NT explicitly says that this prophecy was fulfilled by Jesus in places like Matt 4:16. See also Acts 26:18, Rom 13:12, Eph 5:8, 11, etc.

Barnes addresses this point clearly:

> **The light shineth in darkness** - Darkness, in the Bible, commonly denotes ignorance, guilt, or misery. See Isaiah 9:1-2; Matthew 4:16;
> Acts 26:18; Ephesians 5:8, Ephesians 5:11; Romans 13:12. It refers
> here to a wicked and ignorant people. When it is said that "the light
> shineth in darkness," it is meant that the Lord Jesus came to teach an
> ignorant, benighted, and wicked world. This has always been the case.
> It was so when he sent his prophets; so during his own ministry; and
> so in every age since. His efforts to enlighten and save men have been
> like light struggling to penetrate a thick, dense cloud; and though a
> few rays may pierce the gloom, yet the great mass is still an
> impenetrable shade.